# How do I calculate the last iteration of a PHP while loop with jQuery/JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

In PHP I have a page that checks if there are more than 0 rows and if not then the user gets a message saying `echo 'NO MATCHES';`, then checks if the user `$_POST`ed any *filters* to show all data that fits in said *filtered* parameters and if not shows all iterations. Here's my pseudo code:

**PHP.php**

```
$rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($result); //Count iterations

if($rowcount > 0){

    if(isset($_POST["filter1"]) && isset($_POST["filter2"]) && isset($_POST["filter3"])) {

        //If there are filters selected
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

            include('Listing.php');

        }

    } else {

        //If no filters have been selected
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

            include('Listing.php');

        }

    }

} else {

    echo '<div class="NoMatch">NO MATCHES</div>';

}
```

Then in my jQuery I have an AJAX call that when an image with the `#Loader` is inView (a third party function) it grabs my filters as data, directs to the PHP page (above) and appends the data inside the container. Here's that pseudo code:

**jQuery.js**

```
$('#Loader').on('inview', function(event, isInView) {

        if (isInView) {

            // Filters
            var filter1 = get_filter('filter1');
            var filter2 = get_filter('filter2');
            var filter3 = get_filter('filter3');

            $.ajax({

                url: 'PHP.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {

                    filter1: filter1,
                    filter2: filter3,
                    filter3: filter3
                },

                success: 

                    function(data) { 

                        if(data != '') {
                            $('#StoneContainer').append(data);
                            $('#pageno').val(nextPage);
                        } else {
                            $('#StoneContainer').html(data); 
                            $('#Loader').hide();   // Hide infinite scroll
                        }

                    }

            });

        }

    });
```

In the `if` statement of my jQuery.AJAX i'm trying to hide the image (`#Loader`) when `data` is empty but it's never empty because of my PHP's `echo 'NO MATCHES';`. How do I calculate the last index of the PHP's while loop with jQuery to hide the image when there are no more PHP iterations?

**ATTEMPTS**:

```
if(data.lastIndexOf('class="Iteration"') == 0) {
    $('#Container').append(data);
    $('#pageno').val(nextPage);
} else {
    $('#Container').html(data); 
    $('#Loader').hide();   // Hide infinite scroll
}
```

Didn't work because it would find the last class of that page but not the entire array and `if(data.indexOf('class="Iteration"') > 0) {` didn't work because it only hides when the PHP `$rowcount < 0` but not when the array is finished.

```
$('#Container').append(data);
$('#pageno').val(nextPage);

$('.Iteration').each(function(element) {
    if (element + 1 === count) {
        $('#Loader').hide();   // Hide infinite scroll
    } 
});
```

I can't figure out why didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry - I can't comment yet, but I think this is a reasonable answer -

Why not simply change your if() condition, to exclude whatever the 'no match' condition text looks like.

Your comments seem to indicate that the 'no match' text looks like this:

```
<div class="NoMatch">NO MATCHES</div>
```

Let's say that the string 'NoMatch' is guaranteed to only show up when there are no matches, and will never show up when there were 1 or more matches.

Then you could use this:

```
if(data !== '' && !data.includes('NoMatch')) {
  $('#StoneContainer').append(data);
  $('#pageno').val(nextPage);
} else {
  $('#StoneContainer').html(data); 
  $('#Loader').hide();   // Hide infinite scroll
}
```

Comment: That was just pseudo code but `if(data != '' && data != 'NO STONES MATCH THAT') {` didn't work.

Comment: Because `data` is never empty and I can't figure out why `data != indexOf('class="Error"')` doesn't work

Comment: OK, what is the content of data then? have you looked at it in, say, console.log()

Comment: `console.log(data)` prints all the iterations inside the PHP's `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {` loop. 

Then, when adding of a filter where there are no matching iterations `console.log(data)` prints `<div class="NoMatch">NO MATCHES</div>`

Comment: The goal is to exclude whatever the one 'no match' row looks like. You could compare data != '<div class="NoMatch">NO MATCHES</div>' for example (whatever the no match row looks like). Or you could use javascript String.includes() and look for a smaller but unique pattern of text that signifies no match. I'll go edit the answer to show you what I mean.

Comment: I found that `if(data.indexOf('class="NoMatch"') > -1) {` works for that. 

But my problem is when there is `data` showing and there is no more `data` after that I want to hide `#Loader` to not confuse the user. Any idea how I can check future iterations of `data` before AJAX loads it? I started reading about [jQuery.promise()](https://api.jquery.com/promise/). Am I going down the right path?

Comment: My new idea is to 1) append `data` to `#Container` 2) run `.promise()` function which promises `$('#pageno').val(nextPage);`. Inside said function, if `data` (on the next page) is empty and `data.indexOf('class="NoMatch"') > -1` then `$('#Container').html(data);` (to show error message) and hide `#Loader` otherwise (`else`) `$('#StoneContainer').html(data);`. 3) Loop the AJAX `success` from the beginning. I have to learn about `jQuery.promise()` to do this. Does it make sense at your level though?

Comment: @ArielZabihi - give me a bit more here. What do the real lines look like? I see that the one line that comes back when there is nothing is the one with class="NoMatch". What do the other lines look like? Maybe give me a sample of a few lines, showing first and last line. I think you're not going to need anything like a promise. You just want to loop through the lines till you get to the end.

Comment: Here is [a dump of my jQuery](https://pastebin.com/eDNsTesF), [a dump of my PHP](https://pastebin.com/uiCG5MDC) and [a dump of my listings](https://pastebin.com/5btYrTMk)

Comment: @ArielZabihi that's a lot of stuff to work through. I don't blame you for dumping them, but it's more than I care to try to deal with. All I want is something like this - there are two cases - 1) no match. I know it's no match because my console.log(data) output has 'class="NoMatch"' in it. and 2) it's something else, and here are a few lines from that console.log(data) - the first one, one or two from the middle, and the last one. That's all I need!

Comment: Oh sorry about that!! I guess I didn't understand the question. Here are the three cases; [CASE1](https://pastebin.com/aSMduh8g) - when all rows are show. [CASE2](https://pastebin.com/fyTKfwN7) - when specific rows are requested and shown. [CASE3](https://pastebin.com/Q5kRrcve) - there are no rows to show

Comment: OK, I think I get it, or closer now. Let me try to return to one thing you've been sort of asking all along - you've got a $rowcount in php.php. Fine. It is controlling how many iterations of output are happening (which may be none). Various things create echo output. You'd like to get that output, and if possible the rowcount. HOW ABOUT THIS? -- your echoes are appended to a variable instead. One big string variable. When you're ready to echo, you do a json_encode.

Comment: $out = "<civ>...</div>"; (later) ... $out .= "<div>...</div>"; (etc); and you have $rowcount. Put them into an array, json_encode that array, echo the encoded array, then decode it on the javascript side. Then you'll have the echo output. And you'll have the $rowcount.  Thus - $final = array(); $final["rowcount"] = $rowcount; $final["output"] = $out; ... then one last echo json_encode($final); . . . on the javascript side, new = JSON.parse(data); ... within that new you'll have new.rowcount with the row count, and new.data with the same data as before. Will that get you where you want to go?

Comment: `$rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($result);` This just counts the itaritions on the current page. If I `JSON.parse()` it as a variable in my .js file. How can I use it? Sorry i'm really new to JavaScript.

Comment: I give up. I've tried, but there's just too much to explain. Let someone else try. I wish you well. If I can figure out a way to delete my answer, I will.